# Why is intercept_ an array in sklearn linear regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In [sklearn linear regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), `intercept_` returned is an array and not a scalar. Why so?

Other type of regressors, for example [HuberRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.HuberRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.HuberRegressor) allow `intercept_` to be returned as scalar. So code consistency throughout the api should not be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rephrase your question as "why some algorithms return `intercept_` as a scalar value?"

For multiple features we usually need multiple biases (`intercepts`) if we are talking about linear models...

In [HuberRegressor](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/huber.py#L275-L278) the intercept is set explicitly to a scalar value:

```
if self.fit_intercept:
    self.intercept_ = parameters[-2]
else:
    self.intercept_ = 0.0
self.coef_ = parameters[:X.shape[1]]
```